# How to groupby 200 features at once using Julia

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I am looking for a way to perform these operations in julia:

From a daframe I have 200 columns that I want to **groupby one-by-one** doing this:

```
column1_grouped = combine(df,column_1),[:fixed_parameter] .=> mean)
column2_grouped = combine(df,column_2),[:fixed_parameter] .=> mean)
```

untill `column200_grouped`.

Is there a way to iterate over a list of these *200 columns* to output these 200 grouped dataframes? (I want to avoid type 200 lines like the above)

I got the list of 200 columns doing:  `list = names(df[!,r"factor_"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where the result will be a `Dict` mapping grouping column name to resulting data frame:

```
list = names(df, r"factor_")
Dict([n => combine(groupby(df, n), :fixed_parameter => mean) for n in list])
```